# I'm using rake for a non-rails app, and migrations using active-record. How to run seeds?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a non-rails application where I use both rake and activerecord for my db migrations etc.

How could I use seeds?

I created a seeds.rb file, but how to wrap it in a rake method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `require_relative 'db/seeds'` if using Ruby 1.9, or `require 'db/seeds'` if using Ruby 1.8 inside a rake task. They will be evaluated when you call it.

Comment: btw, have a schema.rb file, how can I drop and restore from it?